# Add captcha to responsive bootstrap contact form

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new to bootstrap. I have a contact form that is working properly. However, I would like to add a captcha to the form to help eliminate unwanted SPAM mail. How can I add a captcha to my existing form or any other "are you human" option to the form (i.e. would a simple checkbox work) and make it responsive as the current form is? Below is the code for my form:

```
 <section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Contact Me</h2>
                <hr class="star-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                 <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row control-group">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                            <label>Message</label>
                            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can use google recaptcha. Please refer [this](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro)

Comment: These may help: https://github.com/jonmbake/bootstrap3-contact-form  http://raincaptcha.driversworld.us/

Comment: @Jay Chakra how do I update the php for the recaptcha? I got the client-side setup, but not sure how to update the server side (php) to verify Google has checked the user.

Answer (score 0):

Google ReCaptcha is a great tool for this and Google is also preparing a Captcha where no user input would be needed.

To implement a ReCaptcha, you will need to do following:

1. Create Google ReCaptcha API key
2. Paste the code into your HTML. Basically a div and some JS.
3. Validate the response when the form is submitted.

You can follow the step-by-step tutorial here: https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-recaptcha.